# hay alguna forma de replicar una pagina cada vez que se hace un POST? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, archivo, xampp, post

Estoy trabajando con un sistema de reportes, cada vez que se haga un POST registrando un reporte necesito que se genere un archivo individual por cada reporte con sus datos de manera automática, pensé en hacerlo con FOpen cada vez que se realizara el POST de Registro del reporte pero me di cuenta que por la complejidad del archivo seria imposible hacerlo por lo que me pregunto si conocen alguna otra manera de realizar ese trabajo efectivamente.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], recuerda realizar el [tour] y revisar [ask]. Tu pregunta está basada en opiniones y puede estar sujeta a ser cerrada. Además la pregunta está confusa, en el titulo hablas de "replicar una página", en la descripción hablas de crear un archivo de "alta complejidad" (de lo cual tampoco das detalles).

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.